# Can't install BlackArch on Live USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, iso, bootable

So I have the following problem.

I want to install BlackArch on an USB.

I downloaded the Live ISO (64Bit) and used PowerISO to make a bootable USB. I am on Windows 8.1 so I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, went to Settings, holded <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit restart.

Then I booted from the USB. After that this error showed up:

```
Failed to start loader.efi: Not found"
```

Also the file `vmlinuz.efi` was not found.

After that I used the Fedora Media USB Creator. After booting from the USB the loader was found but then the next error showed up:

```
:: Mounting '/dev/disk/by-label/BLACKARCH_201601' to 'run/archiso/bootmnt'
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201212 ...
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/BLACKARCH_201601' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

So I found out that I have to rename the USB to `BLACKARCH_201601` but there is a problem. The max length for renaming is 11 characters. So I googled and found out that I can change the label with an `autorun.inf` file. But that didn't work. Secure and Fastboot are disabled. Its an ASUS Laptop with Windows 8.1 and UEFI.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Okay so now I checked out the Files on the USB Stick and there was a `.conf` file which had a line Called `label=BLACKARCH_201601`. I changed it to `ARCH_EFI` and renamed the USB `ARCH_EFI`. That worked! Now he could mount `/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_EFI`. But now there is a new error:

```
Failed to mount /dev/loop0
```

Comment: Use another software to make the USB key. Read: [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_Windows)

Comment: @cylgalad Ok I tried "Rufus" now which is mentioned on the Wiki. Same problem tho. Rufus created a simple Autorun.inf aswell

Comment: Have you tried the good old `dd` method (on a Linux machine)?  Btw, there's a more recent version (2016-04-28) on [Blackarch](https://www.blackarch.org/downloads.html) maybe they fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `dd` command, I've tried with `Win32Imager` and gotten far but `mkfs` has issues, install guide even says to use `dd`.

Easiest is to fresh install Arch, download BlackArch and execute:

`sudo dd bs=512M if=blackarch-linux.iso of=/dev/sda;`

Comment: Overwriting `/dev/sda` would be a sure way to break most installations as they boot from that drive.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you want to run BlackArch from a USB(Live/Persistent) you need to do a Linux to Linux install.  As another person has said here, you can **not** use Win32DiskImager, Universal USB Installer, or any other USB 'Flasher'.  You have to use `dd` in a Linux installation.

I spent two weeks trying to do it myself, but you just can't get there.  Too much work. Too many errors.  Syslinux and then cfg problems ensue.